# How should my homepage be placed?

Tags: website-design, usability

I'm building a local business directory/things to do website homepage for my city. We try to solve the problem of "What should I do today?". This is the way I've came up with so far.

(the bigger a chunk of color is, the bigger that part will be on my actual website)

[image]

The closest site I can think of that I want my website to look like is Yelp. I think they've done a good job on the UX side of things.

Imagine you came to this website (and also that you lived in my city!) and you were presented with a layout like this? Is this good from a usability standpoint?

Comment: I know the title of this post is terrible, but I didn't know what else to say...Sorry for that!

Comment: There's really not enough information here to properly answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout might work if it fits into one viewport. When information start taking place outside the viewport the use have to start scrolling. You want to avoid having the most important information beneath the first view in my opinion.

Ask yourself what the most important things are and focus on making them stand out. As you mention to solve the "What should I do today?" problem I would give that part more focus.

Comment: But beware... http://iampaddy.com/lifebelow600/

Comment: I was waiting for that one ;)

But still placing the most important information in the best position should be considered important to make it clear.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed so :) Still we need to present a balanced view - otherwise the questioner might bring all the content above-the-fold, making the site look cramped. You know, everything is important on some level...